# Как узнать, как будет выглядеть предлагаемый в PR файл?

Tags: git, github, markdown

Можно ли на гитхабе в PR посмотреть, как выглядит изменённый файл? То есть не дифф, не изменения, а именно как будет выглядеть изменённый файл.

Например, если PR был в README.md, то хочется видеть, как он будет рендерится на гитхабе по итогу, а не текстовые изменения строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В commits заходите в нужный файл, жмете в правом верхнем углу кнопку с листком ("Display the rich diff"), тогда отобразится изменения во внешнем виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо на три точки, в открывшемся меню - "View file", тогда отобразится сам файл после изменений (в режиме просмотра, а не исходник).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточню, что Display reach diff кнопка есть только для файлов, которые гитхаб будет рендерить. На обычном `.c` файле её нет.

Comment: @Кирилл, во-первых вы показываете дифф .c файла, там по идее и не должно быть никакого "rich" варианта, нужно дифф md файл смотреть. Во-вторых у меня нигде "под рукой" нет PR с md файлом, не могу посмотреть как должно отображаться, ориентируюсь на просто дифф в коммите.